# slide out menu won't position where I want it

Tags: menu

I can't get my nav menu right. The slide out sections appear about ten or twenty pixels below the menu item they are supposed to slide out from.

Here's the HTML:

```
<nav><ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" TabIndex="10">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html" TabIndex="20">About Us +</a>
    <ul>    <li><a href="index.html" TabIndex="30">Background</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" TabIndex="40">Designing</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" TabIndex="50">Production</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li><a href="index.html" TabIndex="60">Promotions</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html" TabIndex="70">Products +</a>
    <ul>    <li><a href="index.html" TabIndex="80">Dinnerware</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" TabIndex="90">Ornaments</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" TabIndex="100">Pots</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" TabIndex="110">SumWare Else</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li><a href="index.html" TabIndex="120">Orders +</a>
    <ul>    <li><a href="index.html" TabIndex="130">Order Forms</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" TabIndex="140">Special Request</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li><a href="index.html" TabIndex="150">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
nav {
font-family: impact, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top:10px;
clear:both;
}

nav ul {
padding-left: 20px;
width:100px;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #fbd0bd),color-stop(0.90, #E89C23));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #fff9f4 0%, #fbd0bd 99%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #fff9f4 0%, #fbd0bd 99%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #fff9f4 0%, #fbd0bd 99%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #fff9f4 0%, #fbd0bd 99%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff9f4 0%, #fbd0bd 99%);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto;
border-top: 2px solid #7c3d31;
border-right: 2px solid #7c3d31;
}

nav ul li {
display: block;
position: inline;
}

nav li ul{
display:none;
position: absolute;
margin-left:100px;
padding:0em;
clear:both;
z-index:0;
 }

 nav ul li a {
 padding:15px;
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#7c3d31;
}

nav ul li ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;

}

nav ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0.9;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li a {
display:block;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left, right,color-stop(0, #fbd0bd),color-stop(0.90, #E89C23));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #fff9f4 0%, #fbd0bd 99%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #fff9f4 0%, #fbd0bd 99%);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #fff9f4 0%, #fbd0bd 99%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #fff9f4 0%, #fbd0bd 99%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fff9f4 0%, #fbd0bd 99%);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto;
    color:#7c3d31;
    width: 90px;
    text-align: center;
border-bottom: 2px solid #7c3d31;
border-right: 2px solid #7c3d31;
border-left: 2px solid #7c3d31;
}

 nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
 background:#fbd0bd;
 color:#7c3d31;
}
```

Please help. I figure out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imo this side menu would have been done better design wise, leaving that aside and answering your problem,Html elements have a default styling on their own eg unordered list within a list item goes below it by default padding , you can debug it with chrome / firefox developer tools to find such problems.

```
 nav ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Needs to be changed to

```
  nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.9;

    margin-top: -50px; /*This needs to be added*/
    }
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help. Worked perfectly. Also, I understand that my design isn't great, but I'm still working on it as I'm still studying these things.

Comment: Great glad it worked for you , lil tip here try searching in google for Bootstraps it might give you a jump start on the website you are designing.From what i can see you are using Px to define height / width in most parts which is kinda bad practice if you want it to be compatible with many devises of different screen sizes. Try to use percentages derived from parent container.

Answer (score 1):

To make a standard fly-out menu, you should make the **parent li** item positioned 'relative' and the **sub ul** positioned 'absolute' and top 0, just like this:

```
nav ul li {
    display: block;
    position: inline;
}
```

changed to

```
nav ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

and the positioning of 'nav li ul' modified to:

```
nav li ul{ position:absolute; top:0;left:100%; margin-left:0;}
```

This would be OK.
But usually it's better to link the ul and li with children link symbol '>', because sometime you may want to add 3rd level sub-menu.
So the code above should be

```
nav>ul>li{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
nav>ul>li>ul {
  position:absolute; top:0;left:100%; margin-left:0;
}
```

You could take some templates for learning. There are many good menu templates shared on MenuSo.